# Include a file from a specific source folder in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java project which I want to build in gradle and the source is in the following structure,

```
src
 |
 +-main
 |  |
 |  +-java
 |     |
 |     +-package
 |        |
 |        +- Utils.java
 |        +- Other.java
 |        +- Files.java 
 |        +- Folders.java
 +-awesome
    |
    +-java
       |
       +-package
          |
          +- Utils.java
```

Now, I would like to build the files from the sourceSet `src/main/java` but including the `Utils.java` in `src/awesome/java` instead of from the `main` sourceset.

I have tried the following options (unsuccessfully):

**1. Giving the full file path in `exclude`:**

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "src/awesome/java"
            exclude "${projectDir}/src/main/java/package/Utils.java"
        }
    }
}
```

> Output: error: duplicate class package.Utils

Looks like giving the full file path does not work in the exclude pattern.

**2. Using 2 java closures:**

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude "package/Utils.java"
        }
        java {
            srcDir "src/awesome/java"
        }
    }
}
```

But this removes the `Utils.java` class from both the source locations.

Is it possible to provide a single source file from another location in gradle?

Note: I cannot compile the `Utils.java` class alone since it has dependencies with the other classes. (I know it's bad, no need to rub it in).

Also copying the file to the `main/java/package` location is not possible since it could pollute the SCM.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you insert a task into the DAG to merge the sources and build the merged folder

Eg:

```
sourceSets.main.java {
   srcDirs = ["$buildDir/mergedSources"]
}
task mergeSources(Type:Copy) {
   from 'src/awesome/java'
   from 'src/main/java'
   duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE // (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DuplicatesStrategy.html#EXCLUDE)
   into "$buildDir/mergedSources"
}
compileJava.dependsOn mergeSources
```

> Also copying the file to the main/java/package location is not possible since it could pollute the SCM.

Assuming you are already excluding `$buildDir` from SCM this won't 'pollute' SCM

Comment: Thanks... This would work very well, though I was also able to exclude the required file using closures as said in my own answer. Which one do you think is a better approach?

Comment: If yours works in your IDE then I'd use that since it doesn't require the copy. I have a feeling that eclipse / intellij won't support that so you'll have conflicts with what gradle builds and what eclipse / intellij builds

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we can exclude specific files using the `exclude(Closure)` or `exclude(Spec)` methods instead of passing Strings.

Here's how I achieved it,

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "src/awesome/java"
            exclude { fileTreeElement ->
                fileTreeElement.file.equals("${projectDir}/src/main/java/package/Utils.java" as File)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, it includes the `Utils.java` from awesome subfolder and excludes the `Utils.java` from main subfolder.

Comment: If I were you I'd dynamically subtract `src/main/java` from `src/awesome/java` so you can add more files to `src/awesome/java` and they'll override without extra config required (rather than hard-coding package/Utils.java)